# Change Jekyll site baseurl without breaking links to existing posts

Tags: url, redirect, migration, jekyll

I have a Jekyll blog using the Minimal Mistakes theme. It's hosted through GitHub Pages, with a custom domain name. The github repo is called eg `me.github.io`. Currently, the blog is at something like `http://www.example.com`, so each post comes up like `http://www.example.com/trouble-with-urls/`.

I want to change it so that it's all at `http://www.example.com/blog` instead. I have added `baseurl: "/blog"` to my `_config.yml` file and now the posts are at the right place, `http://www.example.com/blog/trouble-with-urls/`. However, I now have two problems: all my image links are broken, and more importantly the links to individual posts are also broken.

Is it possible to automatically redirect posts? I looked at the `jekyll-redirect-from` gem, but I don't really understand it. It looks like the baseurl is automatically included in the path for the `redirect_from:` and I can't work out how to ignore it. The [readme](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from) for that gem says, for customising, "Simply create a layout in your site's _layouts directory called redirect.html." Is there something I can do with that?

Actually I would also like to change the permalinks as well, to add dates, but I'm trying to focus on one problem at a time! Eventually the final URL of each post should be like `http://www.example.com/blog/2021/02/13/trouble-with-urls/`.

For the images, they are currently all hardcoded like `![url trouble](/assets/images/2021-02/ugh.png)`. I can fix the path by adding in "/blog", to make it `![url trouble](/blog/assets/images/2021-02/ugh.png)` but I think this might be a bad way to link images anyway. I saw that there are `{% %}` tags for links but can't find any resources about using them for images. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working, so here's what I did in case anyone else tries similar in future.

Adding a `baseurl` in `_config.yml` didn't work. Instead, I duplicated my repo, to take advantage of Github Pages' allowance for 1 User site but many Project sites.

One repo remained as `me.github.io`. I renamed the copy to `blog`, and added a `gh-pages` branch. This made GitHub automatically deploy it at `me.github.io/blog`.

Within the `blog` repo, I changed the permalinks to the style I wanted. The images were fine as the relative paths hadn't changed.

Within the original `me.github.io` repo, I first changed the home page (by editing the Minimal Mistakes html files) to hide all posts. Then I added a link at the top of the page to their new home, at `me.github.io/blog`. The blog is now successfully a subsidiary of the main site.

So that old links wouldn't break, I kept all the existing post files in the `me.github.io` repo. I used the jekyll-redirect-from gem to add redirects into each post for the new address. This was done by manually adding a line into the Front Matter of each, saying eg `redirect_to: http://www.example.com/blog/2021/02/13/trouble-with-urls/`. I also deleted all the post content of these posts, so only the Front Matter was left.

All future posts will be made within the `blog` repo, and so they will have the correct URLs.